# Autocomplete textarea with multiple values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textarea

Is there any code example how to make an autocomplete textarea that allow user to type multiple values. Suggestions to autocompletelist must come from ldap. I use Spring framework.

Answer (score 8):

You can try these Jquery plugins for this

[At.js plugin](https://github.com/ichord/At.js)

OR

[Jquery-Textcomplete](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/)

OR

[Bootstrap-Tag-Autocomplete](http://sandglaz.github.io/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/)

Comment: Thank you very much. http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/ is exactly what I need. Others seem to be fine as well, but I liked jquery-textcomplete

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
    });
   });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
<textarea id="tags"><textarea>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Visit this link for more detail
I used textarea instead of input field.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Great Ans! Very useful

Answer (score 0):

did you look into jquery-ui autocompletion? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: What kind of controller method should I put in place of ".php" in spring? Just .html and map it to method that returns a String?

Comment: well, not really. take a look: http://loongest.com/spring-mvc/jquery-ui-autocomplete-and-spring-mvc-explain/

Comment: It is very difficult to me to understand how the script and method which returns the suggestion list work together. I'm a newbie. Can you still help me?